HTF Open plot differs from real Open price
In MQL5 I can use a function like this to store a number of OHLCT-values for a special timeframe in one call:
`
MqlRates mql_rates[];
// Copy historical prices from the desired timeframe
int copied_bars = CopyRates(_Symbol, TimeFrame, 0, BarsLookback, mql_rates);`

Is there something similar in pine for tradingview, I dont want to call request.security for every bar to collect the data.
In the end I want to collect the OHLCT HTF prices for the last n bars.
I tried to call request.security but when calling it for every bar the performance is bad. I also cant use it in a conditional statement like if barstate.islast.
